# Using AdvancedSearch fails on deleted items in Outlook

Tags: vba, search, outlook

I'm trying to execute search on the Deleted Items folder but I get following error `Run-time error '-2147023281 (8007064f)': The operation failed` on line `Set Search = ...`. Code runs without problem on Inbox but fails to run on any other folder.

```vb
' Program.bas standard module

Option Explicit

Public Sub FindAndOpenMail()

    Dim Query As String
    ' Construct filter. 0x0037001E represents Subject.
    ' ci_phrasematch is taken from Filtering Items Using Query Keywords (MS DOCS).
    Query = "https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001E" & _
            " ci_phrasematch 'Inactive'"
        
    Dim Search As Search
    Set Search = Application.AdvancedSearch("Deleted Items", Query)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you try the above code inside the `Outlook` application, or an automation from a different one (Excel, Word etc.)?

Comment: See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information about the `AdvancedSearch` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AdvancedSearch` required four parameters. Each of them build in a specific way. Your code tries it with only two parameters, which is wrong. Theoretically the third and fourth parameters are optional, but the last one **is required** for the code to work as it should.

In order to make it working it is not so simple as it looks... `AdvancedSearch` works in a different thread and it is necessary for the code **to know** that the search has been completed.

Outlook exposes `AdvancedSearchComplete` event which is triggered and it must be used, to change a boolean variable value, which to 'inform' the code to continue with the next steps.

I asked a question in a comment and according to your answer I can continue with a piece of working code. Since you try it in that way, it looks that you did not study too much the method in discussion, no offence...

Supposing that you try the code inside Outlook application and need only a solution for the code line returning the error, the first function parameter should be built as:

```
  Dim delIt As Folder, sc As String 'the Scope parameter
  Set delIt = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
  sc = "'" & delIt.FolderPath & "'"
  'then call the method as:
  Set Search = Application.AdvancedSearch(sc, Query)
```

Comment: No offence taken. I'm aware of a need of `AdvancedSearchComplete` event and additional flag. I've posted this piece of code, because I have only problem with one line, not the entire suite.

Comment: @FlameHorizon Then, it would be much simpler to try correcting your code than building one. How does your code deal with the `flag` you are talking about? I am afraid that this is only the **first** issue. And you still did not answer my question...

Comment: Problem solved. I've needed to surround `Scope` name with `'`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify search scope you would need to specify each folder path or name with apostrophes, for example:

```
Public m_SearchComplete As Boolean  
  
Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search)  
    If SearchObject.Tag = "MySearch" Then  
        m_SearchComplete = True  
    End If  
End Sub  
  
Sub TestSearchForMultipleFolders()  
    Dim Scope As String  
    Dim Filter As String  
    Dim MySearch As Outlook.Search  
    Dim MyTable As Outlook.Table  
    Dim nextRow As Outlook.Row  
    m_SearchComplete = False  
    'Establish scope for multiple folders  
    Scope = "'" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder( _  
    olFolderInbox).FolderPath _  
    & "','" & Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder( _  
    olFolderSentMail).FolderPath & "'"  
    'Establish filter  
    If Application.Session.DefaultStore.IsInstantSearchEnabled Then  
        Filter = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" _  
        & Chr(34) & " ci_phrasematch 'Office'"  
    Else  
        Filter = Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" _  
        & Chr(34) & " like '%Office%'"  
    End If  
    Set MySearch = Application.AdvancedSearch( _  
    Scope, Filter, True, "MySearch")  
    While m_SearchComplete <> True  
        DoEvents  
    Wend  
    Set MyTable = MySearch.GetTable  
    Do Until MyTable.EndOfTable  
        Set nextRow = MyTable.GetNextRow()  
        Debug.Print nextRow("Subject")  
    Loop  
End Sub
```

The parameters of the search, as specified by the `Filter` argument of the `AdvancedSearch` method, will return all items in the `Inbox` and `Sent Items` folders where the `Subject` phrase-matches or contains "Office". The user's `Inbox` and `Sent Items` folders are specified as the scope of the search and the `SearchSubFolders` property is set to true. However, only the first parameter is required, others are optional.

Comment: First paragraph precisely answers my question. Thanks.